# Confused about creating longer lived reference to String

Tags: rust, reference, borrow-checker

I'm trying to improve my Rust skills and running into confusion about getting references and lifetimes working how I want.  I am trying to read lines from a string and 'rotate' the last two through a couple variables.

This works:

```rust
fn main() {
    let test_lines = "line 1
        line 2
        line 3
        line 4
        line 5";
    let mut lines = test_lines.lines();

    let mut a = &String::new();
    let mut b = &String::new();
    println!("{} - {}", a, b);

    let temp = lines.next().unwrap().trim().to_string();
    a = b;
    b = &temp;
    println!("{} - {}", a, b);

    let temp = lines.next().unwrap().trim().to_string();
    a = b;
    b = &temp;
    println!("{} - {}", a, b);

    let temp = lines.next().unwrap().trim().to_string();
    a = b;
    b = &temp;
    println!("{} - {}", a, b);
}
```

and produces:

```
 - 
 - line 1
line 1 - line 2
line 2 - line 3
```

But when I try to roll it up in a loop:

```rust
fn main() {
    let test_lines = "line 1
            line 2
            line 3
            line 4
            line 5";

    let mut a = &String::new();
    let mut b = &String::new();

    let temp;
    for line in test_lines.lines() {
        a = b;
        temp = line.trim().to_string();
        b = &temp;

        println!("{} - {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `temp` because it is borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:68:9
   |
68 |         temp = line.trim().to_string();
   |         ^^^^ `temp` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
69 |         b = &temp;
   |             ----- `temp` is borrowed here
70 |
71 |         println!("{} - {}", a, b);
   |                             - borrow later used here
```

I've read over the `explain` for the error, but I don't see the borrow. (And I swear I saw this work once...)

I'm trying to create String objects for each line of the input and keep a couple pointers to the last two lines (for use in other processing). I expect that the 'older' lines will be dropped when a and b are re-assigned.

I can see quite clearly how to do this in C or C++, but not understanding how to get Rust to do this.

Comment: and in case someone says make temp mut...

I tried that and the compiler gives same error with the additional commentary that `mut` isn't needed

Comment: You can't store 2 strings in one `temp` variable... much less more than 2, your first example has **3** different variables all called the same.

Comment: yes, they shadow each other....

Comment: Yes, but the second example has only a *single* `temp` variable which for obvious reasons can't hold multiple distinct strings.

Comment: you are getting to the heart of the matter!  I tried moving the decl for temp into the loop, but then get an error about the lifetime of temp.

```
error[E0597]: `temp` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:17:13
   |
15 |         a = b;
   |             - borrow later used here
16 |         let temp = line.to_string();
   |             ---- binding `temp` declared here
17 |         b = &temp;
   |             ^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
...
20 |     }
   |     - `temp` dropped here while still borrowed

```

Comment: Well when it's inside the loop it only lives until the closing `}`, it's freed then, but that's not long enough to be stored in `a` or `b`. Your code example, to be frank, is quite nonsensical, you can [just remove the references and everything works (provided that you also make `temp` mutable)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=95d25e20b1987ec32f45980f44ecf31c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no advantage if the type of `b` is `&String` instead of `String`.

```
fn main() {
    let test_lines = "line 1
            line 2
            line 3
            line 4
            line 5";
    let mut a;
    let mut b = String::new();
    let mut temp;

    for line in test_lines.lines() {
        a = b;
        temp = line.trim().to_string();  // could be assigned directly to b
        b = temp;

        println!("{a} - {b}");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=92548f8b06d556ecc0623f3a262f472b)

Answer (score 0):

The error message the rust compiler gives you here might be a little confusing because it gives you the problems in the order they appear in your source, not in the order of execution of the loop.

Let's execute the loop in our head, step by step (relevant parts only).

1. In the first iteration

   1. You create a new owned string with `to_string` and store that in `temp`.
   2. You then store a reference to that owned string in `b`. ("`temp` is borrowed here")
2. In the second iteration

   1. You copy the reference from `b` to `a`
   2. You modify `temp` ("`temp` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed")
      This is actually ok to do in some situations, if for example `temp` is borrowed, but the borrow isn't used. But you do use the borrow, in the next step:
   3. You use the reference `a` to `temp` you created before modification ("borrow later used here")

Comments under your question have told you that you can't store multiple strings in one variable (compared to your unrolled example, which has three `let temp`s, which mean there's three strings alive at the same time at the end). This is a hint about what the problem is, but it's not actually the problem rustc complains about; it simply complains about you taking a reference to a variable, modifying the variable, and then using the reference. Change the second and third `let temp =` in your unrolled example to just `temp =` and you will see the same error message (in an easier to understand order).

Comment: thanks! that's a tight explanation.  

Now... how to fix it?  I would _like_ to have 'pointers' a and b to the last two lines that have been read.  Seems like i should be able to set b to line.to_string() (make it owned) each time through and be done with the temp sillness... but can't quit make that work either...

Comment: Well, cafce25 and Kaplan already posted solutions. Removing `temp` from them is [trivial](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ec1e31cc2b3de6a048f851c6dd38268d). Also, `String` already is a pointer (and two lengths) internally, so this doesn't cause any reallocations.